# AjaxFileUpload : Getting the selected value of RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Two **radiobuttonlist(semesterList and sem1course) created with autoPostBack = true** .
[image]

when i click one of the Item of semesterList the corresponding sem1course Item becomes visible.

Now

```
    protected void UploadComplete(Object sender,   AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs      e)
   {

   string sem = semesterList.SelectedValue;
   string course = sem1course.SelectedValue;
   string path = Server.MapPath("~/MCA/" + sem+ "/" +course +"/")+e.FileName;
   AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
   }
```

String sem and course is not getting the selected value and thats why all files are uploaded into ~/MCA/ folder instead of going into corresponding folder..

The uploaded files should go to **" MCA\Sem1\MCA101\ "**  [I have designed the directory structure but files are uploaded into MCA folder]..

Answer (score 0):

Issue is `Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"] = null` when AjaxFileUpload OnUploadComplete event is called.

**Fix for this issue** (C# Code):

Set RadioButtonList selected value in session at page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"] != null)
    Session["Path"] = "//" + semesterList.SelectedValue + "//" + sem1course.SelectedValue + "//";
}
```

Use session value for the creation of filepath:

```
protected void upload(Object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
        string path = string.Empty;
        if (Session["Path"] != null)
            path = Server.MapPath("~//MCA" + (string)Session["Path"]) + e.FileName;
}
```

Comment: @KPL... i did the same ..used session to store the selected value and now it is working..Thank you ..